# How to put dynamically created html in mxgraph in angular scope?

Tags: mxgraph

I am using mxgraph along with angular. When mxgraph loads I creates sidebar and toolbar, etc. dynamically which are not in angular scope. My question is how can I put these in angular scope so that I can use the features provided by angular?

Comment: I've created a react app that was using mxGraph. What I did was that i just used my own html-elements etc. and linked the onClick Events etc. to mxGraph and the div holding the graph workspace.

Comment: On which version of angular you are working?